# Communication between content script (page mod) and popup (panel)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I currently am making a Firefox extension with Firefox add on sdk and I tried to communicate between content script (page mod) and popup (panel) to no avail.

I am using [toolbar button](https://github.com/erikvold/toolbarbutton-jplib) by Erik Vold. Here is my code:

```
var tbb = require('toolbarbutton').ToolbarButton({
    id: 'from-us_button',
    label: 'from-us',
    image: data.url('img/on.png'),
    panel: panel

});

var pageMod = require('page-mod').PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url('recuperation.js')
    ],
  contentScriptWhen : "end",
  attachTo: ["existing", "top"]

});


var panel = require('panel').Panel({
    width: 200,
    height: 500,
    contentURL: data.url('popup.html')

});
```

My popup.html contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

I would like to pass a variable from recuperation.js to popup.js, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to attach *popup.js* to your panel:

```
var panel = require('panel').Panel({
    ...
    contentURL: data.url('popup.html'),
    contentScriptFile:  require("self").data.url("popup.js")  //or data.url() if you already have it set
});
```

Scripts loaded via the `<script>` tags lack the necessary privileges to use `self.port`.

Then add a listener to your page-mod `worker` and relay the message to your panel like so:

```
var panel = ...
...
require('page-mod').PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url('recuperation.js')
  ],
  contentScriptWhen : "end",
  attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
  onAttach: function(worker){
    worker.port.on("recuperation-to-panel",function(msg){
        panel.port.emit("recuperation-to-panel",msg);
    });    
  }
});
```

Then from *recuperation.js*:

```
self.port.emit("recuperation-to-panel",msg);
```

* edit:  It should be `worker.port.on`; Not `pageMod.port.on`.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse but I have an error : "pageMod.port is undefined".

Comment: @seb68 :  Ooops, It should be `worker.port.on`; not `pageMod.port.on`.  fixed.

Comment: Thanks you. I still have an error : "msg is not defined". In recuperation.js, I have `var msg = "hello";`

Comment: @seb68 : Is `msg` getting through okay to `worker.port.on` ?  What does it output when you put `console.error(msg)` in the event handler that relays the msg to panel.js?

Comment: If I put `contentScriptFile: [data.url('recuperation.js), data.url('popup.js')]` in toolbarbutton, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your popup.js you should have an 'addon' global object which allows you to send messages back to main.js. This is documented here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html#Styling%20Trusted%20Panel%20Content

Comment: Thanks, if I could upvote you 10 times, I'd do that. I think this info deserves more emphasis in the docs, it's important but easy to overlook.